# How to Setup Microsoft Dynamic CRM with Azure SQL

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

when installing dynamic CRM , we are only giving instance name for SQL server windows authentication . How can we setup DCRM with azure SQL V12 instead of my on-premise manually installed SQL server. Is this possible or not, I Need a clarification .

Answer (score 0):

Running dynamic CRM on Azure SQL Database is not supported now. If you want to host the data in Azure, you can try to use SQL VM instead.

Comment: Many are saying so , but there is no proof of document which can say "it won't support Azure SQL " officially , I m stuck at this position.

Comment: Thanks For Reply, How to setup the sharepoint app with Azure AD/On-Premises AD and Azure PaaS SQL ?